# How can i set new value to change question for my Story app

Tags: swift, variables, func

I want to change my story according to what the user pick. However, every time I run the app it's always showing the same question. Specifically, line 30 and 41. I don't want to write 0 over there but IDK what to do. I do have 'the structure" to not confuse.
[image]

```
var hikayeler = [
Story(
    title: "Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: 'Need a ride, boy?'.",
    choice1: "I'll hop in. Thanks for the help!", choice1Destination: 2,
    choice2: "Better ask him if he's a murderer first.", choice2Destination: 1
),
Story(
    title: "He nods slowly, unfazed by the question.",
    choice1: "At least he's honest. I'll climb in.", choice1Destination: 2,
    choice2: "Wait, I know how to change a tire.", choice2Destination: 3
),
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a random number when deciding which story to pick:

```
let index = Int.random(0..<hikayeler.count)
```

Another option would be to record which stories the user has seen, to make sure they always get a different one on startup.

It's up to you to decide how you want your app to work.

Edit - in order to keep the story going you need a variable that stores the current index.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var index = 0

    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let variable1 = hikayeler[index]
        ...
        index = variable1
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing that I want to do is continue the story as the user pick. As you can see i do have an array that has a structure includes title, choice1, choice1destination, choice2, and choice2destination. I started with the title it means story 0. however in 'LINE 30' its writing down: var variable1 = hikayeler[0].choice1destination . the hikayeler[0] should change according to what the user pick. IDK how to arrange this.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to remember what the user chose and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

first link both buttons to the same IBAction then use if and else statements to decide what each button should read

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).